# ASP.Net site upload not working

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I have uploaded a site built with asp.net 2.0 in a sub directory created by the plesk control panel. The subfolder name is "test" and it has the same files as root. However I am not being able to browse the files in the test folder, it's showing a directory listing denied message.

Here is the link: http://test.thigassist.co.uk/
even http://test.thigassist.co.uk/default.aspx is not working and asking for authentication, when the same files are working as expected at http://www.thigassist.co.uk/.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable "Directory Listing" in iis to view the list of files. It seems the folder "test" does not have a default page. Is it a shared hosting?

Comment: The folder does have a default file which is "default.aspx" as I have mentioned in the description. It's not working even after that. 

Getting no clue what this could be. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the IIS settings.  You may need to enable anonymous access to the site.

Comment: Any idea how you do that from a PLESK control panel? Is it because the root directory has got a web.config file and the and so does the test folder? But it can have multiple web.configs in diff folders right?